# Capybara: how to find a class by using multiple attributes inside class

Tags: capybara

I want to find first class which includes a particular text(name in this case) and button enabled inside it.

I have my source like this

```
 <div class="some parent class"> 
         <div class="class" id="1">
               <div class="some other name">......</div>
               <div class="button enabled">......</div>
            </div>
          <div class="class" id="2">
               <div class="name">......</div>
               <div class="button disabled">......</div>
            </div>
            <div class="class" id="3">
               <div class="name">......</div>
               <div class="button enabled">......</div>
            </div>

</div>
```

I have tried

```
first('.class',text: 'name')
```

it finds first class with name but disabled button ofcourse. Then I have tried

```
first('.class',text: 'name', text: 'button text')
```

but it looks like it applies OR operator between text parameters and finds class with id 1. Is there a way to apply AND operator between text parameters or any other way to find class in which it has particular text and a button present.
Also want to mention that position of these classes can be random so can not say that find last class simply.

Comment: did you try something like `if find('.class').include?("name") && find('.class').include?("button enabled") ...` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could find *all* of the `div` tags that have the specified text. Then iterate through those to find the first one that also includes the enabled button:

```
all('.class', text: 'name').find { |div| div.has_css?('div.button.enabled') }
```

You might get better performance by using a single XPath expression. However, it is rather unwieldy and not likely worth the effort:

```
first(
  :xpath,
  '//div
    [contains(concat(" ", @class, " "), " class ")]
    [.//text()[contains(., "name")]]
    [.//div
      [contains(concat(" ", @class, " "), " button ")]
       [contains(concat(" ", @class, " "), " enabled ")]]'
)
```

Comment: `all` returns a Capybara#result object (which is Array like) - it doesn't support calling `#find` on it

Comment: @ThomasWalpole, `#find` seems to work for me. It looks like [Capybara::Result includes Enumerable](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/result.rb#L22-L23).

Comment: Whoops - my mistake -- I misread what you were doing and thought you were calling the Capybara find - sorry about that -  FYI the block filtering in my answer keeps it all executed within one find so you don't run into the issues with `all` not waiting and returning non-reloadable results.

Comment: Either way, your answer's format makes more sense. I didn't know that Capybara's `#find` accepted blocks.

Comment: It's new in 2.10+

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to match on the text contained you can use a regex for the `text` option

```
find('.class', text: /name.*button text/)
```

If you want to make sure it includes an actual button element and you're using Capybara v2.10+ you can use a filtering block with something like

```
find('.class', text: 'name'){ |node| node.has_button?('button text', wait: 0) }
```